# Best Practices For Handling Paginated API Results

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ebay-api, semantic-ui-react

I working with the eBay API which has output controlled by pagination.  The max output of any one page is 100 entries.

On my app, I'm attempting to display the results, along with pagination and a client option to display 10, 25, 50 or 100 results on the page.

I have it working (mostly) yet I know there is something fundamentally wrong with my code.

Anytime someone changes the display output number it saves the state as `entries` and makes another call to the API to fetch the data.  This is what my dropdown looks like:

```
const limitOptions = [
  { key: "0", value: "10", text: "10" },
  { key: "1", value: "25", text: "25" },
  { key: "2", value: "50", text: "50" },
  { key: "3", value: "100", text: "100" }
];

const CardPageSizeSelect = props => {
  const onChangeEntries = (event, data) => {
    props.entriesChange(data.value); //this is setting entries state
    props.fetchData(props.query, props.page, data.value); //fetches new data set based on number of entries
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      Records per page:{" "}
      <Dropdown
        inline
        options={limitOptions}
        defaultValue={props.entries}
        onChange={onChangeEntries}
      />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

as you can see above I'm fetching the data from the api when the dropdown for entries shown changes. I'm not actually updating the page state, so the page sent is always one.

It's the pagination, where the new data past page one is retrieved, as shown below (using Semantic UI React), i'm just passing the current page number from the ebay API output

```
     <Pagination
                    activePage={props.pageOutput.pageNumber}
                    totalPages={props.pageOutput.totalEntries / props.entries}
                    onPageChange={handlePagination}
                  />

  const handlePagination = (e, pageInfo) => {
    props.fetchData(props.query, pageInfo.activePage, props.entries);
  };
```

Here's example of pageOuput data recieved with each api call

```
pageOutput: "{"pageNumber":["1"],"entriesPerPage":["10"],"totalPages":["20"],"totalEntries":["194"]}"
```

Can someone recommend a better way to structure this, so that I'm not making a call to the API if I've allready recieved the max 100 results?

Comment: I'd suggest you should always get fresh data, since it may have changed in the meantime.

Comment: oh so you are saying this sort of structure is fine?

Comment: IMHO yes. Unless you want a snapshot in time.

Comment: ok makes sense, thanks Federico!